# Jquery: <a> link click preventDefault() not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I'm trying to prevent a link click from firing if accidentally touched while scrolling in mobile? I have never tried something like this before and am having trouble getting it to work right. I am testing this on a desktop for the time being.
My buttons are structured similar to:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
    <div style="width:100%;height:80px;margin-bottom:50px;">test</div>
</a>
```

I am trying to use the preventDefault() function to override default click actions and check if a the page is being scrolled, or it the click was accidental before allowing it  to work. The logic to check seems to work, however the links navigate on click no matter what i do. I assume this has something to do with the  links behaviour being propogated to the child div, but am not sure.

Below is my script, the problem is in the last $('a').click(); function.

**UPDATE:**

I still need a better way to do it using just the $('a') selector if anyone knows how. Kind of a hack but, if i change the selector to $('a>div') and change the 'targetLink' to $(this).parent().attr('href') it seems to work,  *Is there a way to do this using $('a') only because some of my buttons have more children.*

```
//Mobile accidental scroll click fix:---
//- prevent clicked link from executing if user scrolls after mousedown, until next mousedown.
//- prevent clicked link from executing if user is still scrolling and mouse is down(for slow scrolls)

$(document).ready(function(){
    var self = this,
        scrolling = false,
        mouseDown = false,
        scrollAfterPress = false;
        scrollDelay = 1500,
        linkConditionCheckDelay = 700;

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            self.scrolling = true;
            console.log('scrolling:' + self.scrolling);
            clearTimeout( $.data( this, "scrollCheck" ) );
            $.data( this, "scrollCheck", setTimeout(function() {
                self.scrolling = false;
                console.log('scrolling:' + self.scrolling);
            }, scrollDelay) );

        });

        $(document).mousedown(function(){
                self.scrollAfterPress = false;
                int00 = setInterval(function() { checkScrollAfterPress(); }, 100);//execute every 100ms (while mouse is down)
                self.mouseDown = true;
                console.log('mousedown:'+ self.mouseDown);
            }).mouseup(function(){
                clearInterval(int00);
                self.mouseDown = false; 
                console.log('mousedown:'+ self.mouseDown);
            });

        function checkScrollAfterPress(){
            if(self.scroll === true){
                self.scrollAfterPress = true;
            }
        }

        $('a').click(function(e){
             //prevent default click event behaviour
            var targetLink = $(this).attr('href');
            console.log('clicked on:'+targetLink);
            setTimeout(function() {
                    if(!self.scrolling && !self.mouseDown && !self.scrollAfterPress && targetLink !== undefined){
                        window.location.href = targetLink;
                    }
                }, linkConditionCheckDelay); //add small delay to prevent immeditiate responses between mouse up and start of scroll.
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
});
```

Comment: Try returning false on your .click function. i.e. return false;

Comment: return false still doesn't block it. It somewhat works if i change the selector to $('a>div') which just stops the link from working at all. Also, i would prefer just using the $('a') selector because some of my buttons might have more children.

Comment: if testing on desktop are you taking into consideration the delay built into mobile touch?

Comment: If i change the selector to $('a>div') and change the 'targetLink' to $(this).parent().attr('href') it seems to work, Is there a way to do this using $('a') only because some of my buttons have more children.

Comment: You can use this to get the children of 'a' tags that do not have any children (are leaf nodes -- the innermost children.) ...
`$('a').children(':not(:has(*))')` There is a problem with this, though. If your children hierarchy is not strictly linear, then there could be more than one leaf node per link, and you would have duplicate events under the same 'a' tag.

Comment: I don't understand `if (self.scroll === true)`. `self.scroll` is a function, is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `return false` or `e.preventDefault`

But when you click on that link why your adding `window.location.href = targetLink;`?? which will redirect the user to the given location.Same as link

Try my code below i have removed it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var self = this,
        scrolling = false,
        mouseDown = false,
        scrollAfterPress = false;
        scrollDelay = 1500,
        linkConditionCheckDelay = 700;

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            self.scrolling = true;
            console.log('scrolling:' + self.scrolling);
            clearTimeout( $.data( this, "scrollCheck" ) );
            $.data( this, "scrollCheck", setTimeout(function() {
                self.scrolling = false;
                console.log('scrolling:' + self.scrolling);
            }, scrollDelay) );

        });

        $(document).mousedown(function(){
                self.scrollAfterPress = false;
                int00 = setInterval(function() { checkScrollAfterPress(); }, 100);//execute every 100ms (while mouse is down)
                self.mouseDown = true;
                console.log('mousedown:'+ self.mouseDown);
            }).mouseup(function(){
                clearInterval(int00);
                self.mouseDown = false; 
                console.log('mousedown:'+ self.mouseDown);
            });

        function checkScrollAfterPress(){
            if(self.scroll === true){
                self.scrollAfterPress = true;
            }
        }

        $('a').click(function(e){
             //prevent default click event behaviour
            var targetLink = $(this).attr('href');
            console.log('clicked on:'+targetLink);
            setTimeout(function() {
                    if(!self.scrolling && !self.mouseDown && !self.scrollAfterPress && targetLink !== undefined){
                        //window.location.href = targetLink;
                    }
                }, linkConditionCheckDelay); //add small delay to prevent immeditiate responses between mouse up and start of scroll.
            return false;
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.google.com">
  <div style="width:100%;height:80px;margin-bottom:50px;">test</div>
</a>
```

Comment: the window.location.href = targetLink; allows the link to behave normally if the user is not scrolling a page. (ie. the click was not accidental)

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest another approach and use `jQuery Mobile Events`.  Something like this:
<sup>**untested, but is the idea*</sup>

```
// set global var 'locked'
var locked = false;

// locked var true while scrolling
jQuery(document).on('scrollstart', function() { locked = true; });

// locked var back to false when finish
jQuery(document).on('scrollstop', function() { locked = false; });

// bind 'tap' & 'click' events to 'a' tag
jQuery(document).on('tap click', 'a', function(event) {
    // But before proceed, check locked var
    if (locked) {
        event.preventDefault;
        return false;
    } else {
        // ok, proceed with the click and further events...
    }
});
```

<sup>**Docs/ref:**
[scrollstart event](https://api.jquerymobile.com/scrollstart/)
[scrollstop event](https://api.jquerymobile.com/scrollstop/)
[tap event](https://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/)
[vclick event](https://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/)
[.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Use in your `$'a'.click(function(e){...}` part `return false;` to prevent the default behavior.

In your case:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
        var targetLink = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log('clicked on:'+targetLink);
        setTimeout(function() {
                if(!self.scrolling && !self.mouseDown && !self.scrollAfterPress && targetLink !== undefined){
                    window.location.href = targetLink;
                }
            }, linkConditionCheckDelay); 
        return false;//Stops default behavior
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is something I am missing, but I do not see why your code cannot be made as simple as the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var is_scrolling = false;
    var timeout = null;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        is_scrolling = true;
        if (timeout) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);   
        }
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            is_scrolling = false;
        }, 1500);
    });

    $('a').click(function (e){
        if (is_scrolling) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```